# Turn off acrylic background on Popup (and flyout)

Tags: uwp, themes, uwp-xaml

As in the title: I need to turn off acrylic background on my Popup and also I'd like to turn it off on a Flyout which is under my Popup.

Both of these contain 2 UserControls (1-1).

It literally destroys my near-to-release application.
The flyout under my popup is very disturbingly visible, so my control labels goes from white to gray (silly, hard to read), what most I even have a color picker there with big colored rectangles - you can imagine how bad it is when things from under, like a shadows kicks me from back.

I have tried to overwrite every key stated in the docs, like:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlAcrylicElementBrush" Color="Yellow" />
```

PS. it's very BAD work from MS, forcing it to take effect without a question, and as this happens, not in the first rows in the documentation very clearly emphasize and explain how to turn it off.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello, the default Flyout background is a solid color (not acrylic). Do you mean that Flyout is displayed as an acrylic background by default? Does the problem persist after restarting the device? If so, can you provide a minimal reproducible demo so that I can analyze this problem

Comment: Hi, thx. No, I open the flyout first, it might be solid. That's ok. The flyout has 2 buttons to open the same Popup. The popup is acrylic (or just bad*) and I can see through, see the Flyout.
*It's rather bad. I can't see any controls (blurred) from the Flyout underneath the Popup, but where it overlaps (from under...) it darkens my Popup, like a shadow.
It was not like this, just after I updated NuGet packages, Windows target (18362), while min version is 17763.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT
After all, I found also, it doesn't matter if I request Dark theme in App.xaml, I need to do so also in the user control, to get that in VS designer.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I could reproduce the problem in a demo. I'll upload it somewhere now.

Comment: Link to the demo:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuCHjOfVrncbntkBTXvp94D6s2AA4Q?e=sUXXfX

Comment: Hello, I tested the demo you provided. So far, it does not exhibit the abnormal behavior you described. If this behavior occurs after adjusting the target version of the project, you can delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project and rebuild the project

Comment: I always do it. Deleting, rebuilding doesn't help, that's why you can see it in the demo too - unfortunately. You can see the abnormal and unwanted behavior, it's like drawn out in the wrong order. Even if the Flyout has white or light background, Popup is "shadowed". As there is no z-index and such, what can I do with it? That Popup is unusable now, though it has a very important function in my app.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot next to the sln file in the root folder.

Comment: Hello, this is a strange phenomenon. Tested in the system of 19041 (2004), it behaves normally, it may be repaired in the system of 19041.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your efforts. Nice to know. (My PC hasn't got that version yet.)